# Deleting last element from an array (deleting last row from string)

Tags: javascript, jquery

My textfield has this value:

```
"1  
2  2
3  
4  4
5  a
6  
7  
8
"
```

When I split it by "\n" I get:

```
["1", "2  2", "3", "4  4", "5  a", "6", "7", "8", ""]
```

I want to delete the last element. I'm doing this:

```
$('#textArrayId').val().replace($('#textArrayId').val().split("\n")[$('#textArrayId').val().split("\n").length - 1], "")
```

And I can't get it to delete. What to do?

I want to do this with string operations, not array operations.

Comment: Why are you splitting by newline when that String uses spaces as a delimiter?

Comment: @Jivings The strings are separated by newlines, but you need to put two spaces at the end of a line for the newline to show up in Markdown.

Comment: Your latest edit is not in line with `When I split by "\n" I get:`. Please describe the exact result you want to get, given your input.

Comment: @raina77ow I just want to delete the last element. The array to finish with "8"

Comment: Your question still isn't entirely clear. In the title it says: "delete last row of string", that would be the `8`, but in your question says you want to remove the last element of the array, which is not the `8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the last line, use this

```
var lines = $('#textArrayId').val().split("\n");
var withoutLastLine = lines.slice(0, -1).join("\n");
$('#textArrayId').val(withoutLastLine);
```

Or if you want to remove the last line without whitespace:

```
var lines = $.trim($('#textArrayId').val()).split("\n");
var withoutLastLine = lines.slice(0, -1).join("\n");
$('#textArrayId').val(withoutLastLine);
```

To remove the last element of an array, use this expression to receive all elements but the last:

```
x.slice(0, -1)
```

Comment: Close, but I believe the desired result is obtained by doing this: `$.trim($('#textArrayId').val()).split(/\s+/)`

Comment: @MassivePenguin Sure, if you want to clean all possibly unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: @Srcee Have you tried what I suggested? It should do what you described.

Comment: @phant0m And how to fill the textarea afterwards? I tried $('#textArrayId').val($.trim($('#textArrayId').val()).split("\n")) but it puts all in one line

Comment: @Srcee Depending on how to interpret your question, it should. I have now edited it and added a different version.

Comment: No it shouldn't. It should delete the last element from the array, which is a new line and then an empty space.

Comment: @Srcee In that case, use the first version I have given.

Comment: But it doesn't delete the last line! It deletes the 8.

Comment: @Srcee You're not using the code I have supplied in my most recent edit then. Refresh the page. I have tested it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8mWP/).

Comment: @Srcee As you can see, the code does not remove the `3`, only the blank line and space following it.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to trim off the whitespace before splitting. That way you can handle input more robustly:

```
var lines = document.getElementById('textArrayId').value
               .replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'').split(/\s+/);
```

The regex used in the split will also allow for input like:

```
1    2
  3         4  5 6
 7    8
```

Also note: No jQuery used ^_^

Comment: If you want to ony split on newlines, try this: `.split(/[\t ]*\r?\n[\t ]*/)` - this will also trim off any whitespace at the start and end of lines, and handle the possibility of CRLF instead of just LF.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the  bounded array like a[7] to store the value from 1 to 8 .